# Origin of custom of cantor walking for "Hineni"

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, high-holidays

Prior to the Musaph service on the High Holidays, the cantor recites a prayer called *Hineni*, named after the first word of the prayer meaning "Behold, I am...". The prayer's contents is mainly the cantor's plea that G-d grant him the strength to serve as the congregation's prayer representative and listen to his and the congregation's prayers and requests.

I have notice that in several shuls, the cantor begins the prayer at the back of the shul and slowly walks towards the *bimah* by the time the prayer is completed.

What is the origin of this custom and why is this done?

Comment: I've never seen this...

Comment: According to a friend of mine who works as a conservative cantor, the origin is "old ladies on ritual committees who want to set the cantor up with their granddaughters and I won't do it."

Comment: @Yitzchak There's something to be said about ritual committee ladies who think that marrying a cantor is a great option for their granddaughters. But, I won't say what that is.

Comment: @Yitzchak Over a year later, I'll reveal why I think the ladies are doing that - they think that when the cantor passes their grandaughter singing "Hineini", somehow, he's saying "I'm ready to get married ... to her!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.yale.edu/uvt/fall97/hirsch.html) says:

> The prayer probably dates from medieval times; its authorship is
>   unknown. The hazzanim of nineteenth century Eastern Europe added drama
>   to their recitations of the prayer by approaching the bimah from the
>   rear of the synagogue as they chanted.
>
> A story is told of Hazzan Joseph Altshul of Slonim. His choir would
>   stand on the bimah awaiting his entrance. One choir member would call
>   out, "Where is the hazzan?" The cantor would answer, "Hineni, here I
>   am." A second choir member would call, "Why are you standing in the
>   doorway?" The cantor would reply, "He'ani, I am poor." Then the choir
>   would ask, "Do you need money?" Hazzan Altshul would continue his
>   rendition and elucidate, "He'ani mima'as, I am poor in deeds."

My Conservative shul does this, and from what I have read, this seems to be a common custom in many Conservative and Reform shuls. I haven't seen this done in Orthodox shuls.